# Representing a path for further querying

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, semantic-web, rdflib

Using RDFLib or anything python level API for RDF.

I would like to represent a specific path over several triplets in a closed world assumption.

Say I have

```
(s1, p1, o1)
(o1, p2, o2)
(o1, p3, o2)
```

I would like to say `(s1 p1 / o1 / p3 / o2)` meaning that the specific path by which I want to reach from `s1` to `o2` is via "`p1, o1, p3`" even when more paths exist.

If this is not supported by RDFLib, what would be a good way to represent that so that in the future I could compose a SPARQL query starting from the "path" `(s1 p1 / o1 / p3 / o2)` adding `?p4 ?o3`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question, but do you want to query you're data by just defining parts of the path? Did you have a look at [SPARQL 1.1 property paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths)?

Comment: Just as a joke: use `rdf:List` of `rdf:Statement`s.

Comment: @AKSW I have. I might be misunderstanding but it seems property paths cover linkage for query purposes. How would I express s1 -> p1 -> o1 -> p3 -> o2 ?

Comment: @MaximVeksler ok, I'm puzzled now. Do you want to serialize paths somehow in the RDF dataset or is the question about querying? And yes, the property paths are for a more powerful and flexible way to query paths in the graph - though it's indeed limited.

Comment: @AKSW Maybe a functional perspective would be easier to explain. I would like to define an Injective function f, so that for the graph mentioned in my original question f(s1) = o2. I'm trying to express is that I want to "freeze" the path I've walked on the graph from point a to point b, so while other paths from a to b exist I want to represent the path traversed. I need this because that allow further graph expansion at later stage in the logical flow, path is context to eliminate otherwise valid matches. (also it's possible that comment boxes aren't the best format to have this discussion)

Comment: related discussion https://github.com/w3c/EasierRDF/issues/47